# WSO2 API Manager Customising Roles

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

We are using WSO2 Identity server and WSO2 API Manager to manage access.
We give scopes to API and assign scopes to roles.
Now the requirement came like From the application , privileges for roles has to be manipulable.
Suppose if there is a Role like Admin in the application , we have to list activities[scopes] against that Role and Super User can change the scopes against that Role.Superuser can create new roles as well.
So we cant predefine which are all the scopes for the particular roles.

How can i address this via WSO2? How to manage privilages via WSO2?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want is to manage the permission each role has.

That you can do with `RemoteAuthorizationManager` SOAP service.

See [docs here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Managing+Permissions+with+APIs).

Comment: I am more or less looking for Editing scopes and giving the newly created role into it.So that newly created Role will have privilages to that scope.

Comment: I have my scopes defined in the API Manager.
When super admin adds new role via UI , he should be able to select the scopes and apply to that role.

Comment: As per the current implementation, scopes are not editable.

Comment: How can I solve this?I dont think RemoteAuthorizationManager fits for this

Comment: Any answers for this?We are stuck here.. The roles privilages are dynamic and admin user should be able to configure this.